# Multiple cell Range as Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so please excuse my ignorance :)

I am having trouble writing (and understanding) why my code isn't working in VBA. I am trying to reference multiple cells. My code reads

```
    If sheet4.range("G2:G26").value = "" Then
        Sheet4.range("G2:G26").value = "No Gas"
           Exit Sub
               End If
    End Sub
```

I know I cant use multiple cell as value, but how would I write the code? Also, why am i not able to use multiple cell as value? Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: UNCLEAR...are you testing if **all** cells are blank or if **any** cell is blank ?

Comment: just a certain range of cells g2 to g26

Answer (score 5):

You can assign a value to multiple cells at once:

```
Sheet4.range("G2:G26").value = "No Gas"
```

will put `No Gas` in every cell in the range.

You cannot test a whole range against one value as it is an array and the array does not equal a single value.

You can iterate:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in Sheet4.range("G2:G26")
    If cell = "" then
        cell = "No Gas"
    End IF
Next cell
```

or you can select all the blank ones and fill them at one time:

```
Sheet4.range("G2:G26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "No Gas"
```

Comment: Ok this is starting to make sense. What i am ultimately trying to do is if i entered a number in G2 then it stays as the number i entered. If i didn't enter anything then it will default to "No Gas" Would this code represent that ?

Comment: Either of the last two codes will fill the blanks with 'No Gas' and leave those with values alone.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi Scott,  When I add the 

For Each cell in Sheet4.range("G2:G26")
    If cell = "" then
        cell = "No Gas"
    End IF
Next cell 

and i click the play or run button it doesn't work but the below  code works when ran?

when i add the  Sheet4.range("G2:G26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "No Gas"

Im just trying to get a good understanding of running code.,

i did not create a module for it, i just wrote in sheet 4 as private. The editor lists as "worksheet" and "Activate" Are the settings correct? Just trying to understand making the code run.

Comment: @VBAKOD see edit I forgot to declare cell as a range.

Comment: GREAT, Thank you for the help

Comment: @VBAKOD if this answered your question please mark it as such by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner, you could actually test a whole range against one value by means of  WorksheetFunction.CountIf() method

Answer (score 1):

Or just replace all blank cells:

```
sheet4.range("G2:G26").Replace "", "No Gas", xlWhole
```

Answer (score 0):

From your post it'd seem you want to check a *whole* range against the *same* value

You can do this as follows:

```
With sheet4.Range("G2:G26") '<--| reference your range
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "mysearchedvalue")= .Count Then .Value = "mysubstitutevalue"
End With
```

If you want to check a *whole* range against a *blank* content then you could use the following code:

```
With sheet4.Range("G2:G26") '<--| reference your range
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)= .Count Then .Value = "No Gas"
End With
```

Comment: yes but see the first comment to my answer, OP wants to leave those cells with values alone while replacing only the blank ones with the alternate.

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes but 1) the statement _"You cannot test a whole range against one value"_ wasn't true 2) OP's question wasn't clear 3) Gary'sStudent's clarification request remained unanswered 4) OP hasn't accept your solution yet  So I mainly wanted to make point 1 clear and possibly intercept a (very) hidden OP's request :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. Scott's solution worked perfectly. I am trying to understand the other solutions as well. I really want to be a pro at this.